# Android app dependencies ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, jar, dependencies, classnotfoundexception

I'm new in Android development. Not very new in ordinary EE Java and Gradle.

So I am trying to build a REST consumer app for Android. I have a (1) .jar file I will need (contains DTOs and api consumers). That (1) .jar has dependencies on other (2) jars from Nexus repo. These (2) do depend on other (3) jars (e.g. apache commons lang3, etc.) from maven repos.

The funny thing is that... The app compiles and install just fine. But on runtime it occasionaly tends to lose some classes from (1) (at least (1) -- dunno about (2) and (3) yet).

I know SO does not like pics in questions, but in this case I believe pics = clarity.

See below. Same runtime, same jar. Except one of the classes is not loaded, and another one, sitting right next to it, is available.

[image: Some classes are not seen by the classloader]

[image: And some are seen]

Why is that so? What did I do wrong?

One more thing... If I attempt to instantiate one of the missing classes (there's more than one) in main activity (inside onCreate()), sometimes that class appears in the classpath and creates an object just fine. But as ridiculous as it may sound some other class goes missing! It feels like Classloader has limited number of slots for classes it could possibly handle.

**EDIT:**
Okay, it gets better. It appears that for some reason gradle decided not to include some files from (1).jar into generated .apk...
Any ideas why?

Gradle 4.1. Linux Mint 18. Android Studio 3.0 Canary 8

Left - decompiled APK structure; right - original jar
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you have ProGuard activated. ProGuard removes from the final `.apk` the unused classes. [ProGuard](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html)

Comment: `minifyEnabled` is set to `false`. Tried commenting out the whole `release` block - still no luck